# Core Data freezing main thread

Tags: ios, core-data

I am kinda new to Core Data, and have encountered some wierd stuff when making a point counter for a game.

I have this code for creating a new Point-object for a match (the static holder "button.pointHolder" is not a core data-object):

```
NSLog(@"before block");
[self.match.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"in block");
    PointHolderType *holderType = [self.matchController insertPointHolderForTeam:self.match.homeTeam withStaticHolder:button.pointHolder];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"in block dispatch_get_main_queue");
        //Updating UI
    });
}];
NSLog(@"after block");
```

This seems to block the main thread when my core data is growing. (It doesn't matter if its a new match instance without point holders or not. It is lagging when my core data is growing no matter what)

The logs:

```
2013-11-04 11:48:53.059 [463:60b] before block
2013-11-04 11:48:53.060 [463:60b] after block
2013-11-04 11:48:53.062 [463:60b] in block
2013-11-04 11:48:53.606 [463:60b] in block dispatch_get_main_queue
```

And I'm creating my object like this:

```
- (PointHolderType *)insertPointHolderForTeam:(NSString*)team withStaticHolder:(PointHolder *)holder
{
    PointHolderType *holderType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PointHolderType" inManagedObjectContext:self.match.managedObjectContext];

    holderType.type = [NSNumber numberWithInt:holder.pointCounterType];
    holderType.team = team;
    holderType.points = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:holder.pointsAdded];
    holderType.match = self.match;

    return holderType;
}
```

Also, if i remove this line:

```
holderType.match = self.match;
```

I get a fully responsive UI. This makes me wonder if it has something to do with my managedObjectContext which I'm using from the "match" itself.

Other info:

I'm creating my match like this:

```
Match *newMatch = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Match" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

And my managedObjectContext like this:

```
-(void) useDocument
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"brannboll_document"];

    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url.path])
    {
        //create
        [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if(success)
            {
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
            }
        }];
    }
    else if(document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed)
    {
        //Open it
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
        }];
    }
    else //try to use it
    {
        self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? What am I missing?

EDIT:
Thanks to CouchDeveloper in the comments, I managed to find the root of the problems; My parent Core Data Table View controller, whose fetchrequest got constantly called when adding relations to a Match-object. Why? You tell me. I solved it by nil-ing the actual fetchrequest in viewdiddisappear, and vice verca.

Thanks!

Comment: You might profile the code with Instruments, and tell what exactly is so costly when executing the statement `holderType.match = self.match;`. You may also notice, that `insertPointHolderForTeam` will execute on the main thread, since a `UIManageDocument`'s `managedObjectContext` property is associated to the main thread.

Comment: What trace should I use to get any descent output when working with core data?

Comment: A "Time Profiler" would be sufficient to tell what's going on.

Comment: It seems as if the parent View Controller (which is a CoreDataTableViewController) calls controllerDidChangeContent every time I add an object. This is not what i expected. The fetchrequest is for all objects of type "Match". Why would it make a new request when I add relations to a Match-object?

Comment: Ps. Time Profiler seems to be just AWESOME. Thank you. I wish I could accept your comment as correct answer.